# Why isn't my form data being processed from one page to another in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I am developing the admin panel for my web application.  On the index of the member management section is a list of the newest member accounts.  There is a checkbox for each member that an admin can check to delete multiple users at once.  I use jQuery to submit the form with a link.  Since the form is on the index of the member management section(members/home), I want the process of the form to be on members/delete.  When the members/delete controller is accessed, there is an option of providing a single member ID in a URL segment or the admin can use the form on the members index page.

My problem is that none of the data from the checkboxes is being passed to the members/delete controller.  I have tried $this->input->post('delete_members') and $_POST['delete_members'].  I have also tried changing the method of the form to GET and then $_GET['delete_members'].  I get "Undefined index: delete_members with everything I try.  Any ideas?

PS: I have a route that changes members/delete to members/home/delete

Members controller: (members/home)

```
<?php

class Home extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index($page = 1){

        $this->template->overall_header("Manage Members", array(), array(libs_url('jquery-datatables/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css'), libs_url('jquery-datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css')));

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $data['member_results'] = $this->member->result_array($this->admin['results_per_page'], $page);

        $config = array(
            'base_url' => site_url('members/'),
            'total_rows' => $this->member->total_rows,
            'per_page' => $this->admin['results_per_page'],
            'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
            'full_tag_open' => '',
            'full_tag_close' => '',
            'first_link' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>',
            'first_tag_open' => '<li>',
            'first_tag_close' => '</li>'.PHP_EOL,
            'last_link' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>',
            'last_tag_open' => '<li>',
            'last_tag_close' => '</li>\n',
            'next_link' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            'next_tag_open' => '<li>',
            'next_tag_close' => '</li>'.PHP_EOL,
            'prev_link' => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            'prev_tag_open' => '<li>',
            'prev_tag_close' => '</li>'.PHP_EOL,
            'cur_tag_open' => '<li class="active"><a href="">',
            'cur_tag_close' => '</a></li>'.PHP_EOL,
            'num_tag_open' => '<li>',
            'num_tag_close' => '</li>'.PHP_EOL,
            'cur_page' => $page,
            'uri_segment' => 2
        );

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('members/index_body', $data);

    }

    function delete($member_id = ''){

        /* If a member id wasn't provided in the URL, look for the array of checkboxes */
        if($member_id == ''){

            if(count($_POST['delete_members']) > 0){

                foreach($_POST['delete_members'] as $id){

                    $this->member->delete($id);

                }

                if($this->member->error == NULL){

                    $this->template->overall_header("Request Processed");

                    $data = array(
                        'error_title' => 'Request Processed',
                        'error_message' => 'The members you have requested have been deleted from the database.',
                        'redirect' => 'members'
                    );

                    $this->load->view('error_body', $data);

                } else {

                    $this->template->overall_header("System Error");

                    $data = array(
                        'error_title' => "System Error",
                        'error_message' => $this->member->error,
                        'redirect' => 'members'
                    );

                    $this->load->view('error_body', $data);

                }

            } else {

                $this->error->title('No Members Selected')->message('You did not select any members to delete!')->redirect('members')->display();

            }

        } else {

            $this->member->delete($member_id);

            if($this->member->error == NULL){

                $this->template->overall_header("Request Processed");

                $data = array(
                    'error_title' => "Request Processed",
                    'error_message' => 'The member you requested has been deleted from the database.',
                    'redirect' => 'members'
                );

                $this->load->view('error_body', $data);

            } else {

                $this->template->overall_header("System Error");

                $data = array(
                    'error_title' => "System Error",
                    'error_message' => $this->member->error,
                    'redirect' => 'members'
                );

                $this->load->view('error_body', $data);

            }

        }

    }
```

The form:

```
if(count($member_results) > 0){

    $i = 0;

    $str .= '
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                '.form_open('members/delete', 'id="delete" role="form"').'
                                    <table class="table table-striped" data-sortable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th>Display Name</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Join Date</th>
                                                <th>Actions</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
            ';

    foreach($member_results as $member){

        $str .= '
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete_members[]" value="'.$member['id'].'"></td>
                                                <td>'.anchor('members/modify/'.$member['id'], $member['display_name']).'</td>
                                                <td>'.$member['email_address'].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$member['date_joined'].'</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                                        '.anchor('members/modify/'.$member['id'], '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>', 'data-toggle="tooltip" title="Modify '.$member['display_name'].'" class="btn btn-danger"').'
                                                        '.anchor('members/delete/'.$member['id'], '<i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>', ' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete '.$member['display_name'].'" class="btn btn-danger"').' 
                                                    </div>                          
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
            ';

    }

    $str .= '
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                '.form_close().'
                            </div>
                            <div class="data-table-toolbar">
                                    <ul class="pagination">
                                      '.$pagination.'
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
        ';
}

$str .= '<script>
           $(\'#submit-delete\').on(\'click\', function(e){
if($(\'input[type="checkbox"][name="delete_members[]"]:checked\').length > 0){
    $(\'#delete\').submit();
} else {
    alert(\'You did not select any members to delete!\');
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

});
';

```
echo $str;
```

Comment: where''s the jQuery submit code and redirect? Can't use javascript to redirect to a page that expects post data

Comment: It's at the bottom of the form inside the JS tags $('#delete').submit()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace this line:

```
form_open('members/delete', 'id="delete" role="form"')
```

With:

```
form_open('home/delete', 'id="delete" role="form"')
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using a route to change members/delete to members/home/delete.  Thats why I'm getting PHP errors and not a 404 not found :)

Answer (score 0):

Change method

```
function delete($member_id = '') { 
  // your code here
}
```

to

```
function delete() { 
 echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die;
 // your code here
}
```

Check of your form post is working in few method or not. It POST data in coming in delete method you can do rest of code according to logic.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that none of the checkbox values were being posted because of the jQuery iCheck plugin that came with a theme that I purchased.  I disabled JS when I became skeptical of the theme and, wouldn't you know it, the checkbox values started to post.